# FFMPEG - Green cast with Splash image in video

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, monochrome

I'm using FFMPEG to produce a video consisting of a single monchrome JPG image:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 5 -i SplashBW.jpg Splash.mp4
```

There are two issues with the resulting video:

- When viewed with VLC it has a green cast
- When viewed with "Film and TV" (I suspect this is the Windows 10
  viewer - the association for MP4 files seems to have been hijacked
  on my PC) it has a green cast and a predominant flickering every
  0.5 seconds or so.

When viewed with Irfan View it looks fine.  I don't know whether the issue is with the original JPG, the FFMPEG command, or the viewers.  Naturally, I want it to render properly on all outputs.

The first two links below look fine in my browser (Chrome) when I open them.  The third link is a screen recording of what I see when I try to play the video with the `Film and TV`app.

[B&W image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/plcasmamfy654un/splashBW.jpg?dl=0)

[Resulting video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/noiuq0upm2hoo36/Splash.mp4?dl=0)

[screen grab of video playing on my PC](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0wnt0k5jq3p7hz/Green%20Splash.avi?dl=0)

A log of the FFMPEG run:

```
C:\Users\Raymond\Desktop\Chorus\Videos\Virtual Choir>call ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 5 -i SplashBW.jpg Splash.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libope
ncore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --
enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuv
id --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6ccdd00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6ccde80] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6d59b00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6ccde40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6ccdf00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6ccdfc0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cce180] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cce240] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd33c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd3480] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd3640] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd3700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 19 times
Input #0, image2, from 'SplashBW.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 38348 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), 1 reference frame, gray(bt470bg/unknown/unknown, center), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 000001e6f6cd2ec0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:gray tb:1/30 fr:30/1 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] profile High, level 4.0, 4:0:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chro
ma_me=0 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weigh
tb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Splash.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), gray(center), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f8b98e00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5980] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeksspeed=   0x
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5580] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks1.0kbits/s speed=0.359x
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5580] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5580] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks0.3kbits/s speed=0.828x
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5580] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5580] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd51c0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5580] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5840] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks0.2kbits/s speed=1.16x
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 2 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5300] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5440] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5700] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5980] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5040] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd4f00] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5c40] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6cd5ac0] Statistics: 159785 bytes read, 0 seeks
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=  150 fps= 51 q=-1.0 Lsize=     142kB time=00:00:04.90 bitrate= 237.8kbits/s speed=1.65x
video:140kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.855892%
Input file #0 (SplashBW.jpg):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 151 packets read (24127535 bytes); 151 frames decoded;
  Total: 151 packets (24127535 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (Splash.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 150 frames encoded; 150 packets muxed (143004 bytes);
  Total: 150 packets (143004 bytes) muxed
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6d59240] Statistics: 2 seeks, 4 writeouts
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] frame I:1     Avg QP:18.13  size:131209
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] frame P:38    Avg QP:16.03  size:    87
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] frame B:111   Avg QP:24.33  size:    70
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  0.0%  0.0% 98.7%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] mb I  I16..4:  1.8% 96.0%  2.2%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:100.0%  L0:21.7% L1:78.3% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] 8x8 transform intra:96.0% inter:98.7%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] coded y intra: 94.7% inter: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 37%  5% 34%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 46% 22% 11%  3%  3%  3%  4%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 79%  9%  2%  1%  2%  1%  4%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] ref P L0: 96.6%  0.7%  1.3%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] ref B L0: 96.9%  2.1%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] ref B L1: 94.8%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 000001e6f6d57100] kb/s:227.72
[AVIOContext @ 000001e6f6ccb880] Statistics: 32768 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Comment: Looks fine on all players here on Win 7 - VLC 4, Potplayer, WMP. Share a screenshot, or better, screencap.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0wnt0k5jq3p7hz/Green%20Splash.avi?dl=0 I'm starting to wonder if it's something to do with my video hardware/drivers etc.

Comment: Share full log of conversion command.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 5 -i SplashBW.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p Splash.mp4`

Comment: Bingo!  Like to turn it into an answer (with a little how and why)?.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input image has only one component channel - luminance. Most players deal with H.264 streams containing three component channels - luminance or 'brightness' (Y) and two for chroma or 'color' (U & V). When the H.264 encoder encodes a luma-only stream, it stores it using a syntax which many players don't handle well. So, we tell ffmpeg to add chroma components which will have neutral values (since there's no color valence in the source) before sending it to the encoder. We'll add the most common form of YUV encoding - yuv420p.

So,

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 5 -i SplashBW.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p Splash.mp4
```

Comment: Many thanks again. Where does the flickering arise, as a matter of interest?

Comment: That's due to the handling by the decoder of that player.